# Retrieve data by id

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm retrieving data by choosing name in combobox, but its not showing correct id of the table in case it has duplicate rows, so any one can help me to retrieve data by id,

```
emp_id      firstname    middlename    surname

88          sdf             sdf        sdf 
89          durga           dfg        dfg 
90          Durga           Muthu
```

when I'm choosing `Durga` or `durga` its showing the `emp_id` as 90 only

but if I'm choosing `sdf` its showing the correct id `88`

pls any one help me to sort out

Comment: Can you show us your T-SQL query you're using for this?

Answer (score 1):

may be this one can help you

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'
```

Default Collation of the SQL Server installation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS is not case sensitive.

To change the collation of the any column for any table permanently run following query.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN Column1 VARCHAR(20)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

To know the collation of the column for any table run following Stored Procedure.

```
EXEC sp_help DatabaseName
```

Second results set above script will return you collation of database DatabaseName.

[case-sensitive-sql-query-search](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying do do a `case sensitive' select, is it?

You should use a case sensitive collate.

Try it in your select query:

```
select emp_id from YOUR_TABLE where firstname = 'durga' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
 select emp_id from YOUR_TABLE where firstname = 'Durga' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

If it is what you need, you can change in the table:

```
alter table YOUR_TABLE alter column firstname varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

By the way, are you sure querying by the 'first name' is the best approach?